# match unique groups

Tags: regex

I want to put my product filter in my URL, but to match filter words:

Expected match:

```
filter:city:cityname-type:something-type2:something123-price:1000 

filter:city:cityname-type2:something-type:something123-price:1000 

filter:city:cityname-price:1000
```

To be more precise:
string starts with "filter:" word, and after it, at least one filter must be present. Each filter is name:value

First filter (in this case "city") is mandatory, others are not, also order for others can be changed `(city,type,type2 OR city,type2,type)`. Expected filters are at least 1 - 20.

This is regex I am using

```
^filter:((city:([a-z0-9]+)){1}((-type:([a-z0-9]+))|(-type2:([a-z0-9]+))|(-price:([0-9]+)))*)
```

How can I match each used filter only once, because with this regex above it will match:

```
filter:city:some-price:123-type2:aaa-type2:bbb
```

(type2 is used more than once). And if there is better regex for this please post.

Comment: If lookarounds are supported: [`^(?!(?:.*-type2:){2})filter:((city:([a-z0-9]+))((-type:([a-z0-9]+))|(-type2:([a-z0-9]+))|(-price:([0-9]+)))*)`](https://regex101.com/r/rH1wG1/1)

Comment: this reffers only to type2 filter, I would like to be applied to all possible ones, for example: 

 ^(?!(?:.*-(city|type|type2|price):){2})filter:((city:([a-z0-9]+))((-type:([a-z0-9]+))|(-type2:([a-z0-9]+))|(-price:([0-9]+)))*)

is there a way to make a list like -(city|type|type2|price) instead of specific one -type2 ?

Comment: So, [`^(?!.*(-(?:city|type|type2|price):).*\1)filter:((city:([a-z0-9]+))((-type:([a-z0-9]+))|(-type2:([a-z0-9]+))|(-price:([0-9]+)))*)`](https://regex101.com/r/rH1wG1/2)?

Comment: It works, thanks ! Is there a way to make this code better/shorter/more universal (for more filters) ?

Comment: Edit: it is matching filter:city:some-type2:123-type:aaa-price:111-something:anything-...etc....   it is not what I am expecting.. I would like to match only aceptablle filters, and only once. (not unexpected one: "-something:anything...-etc.."

Comment: I updated the answer. The solution is to add `\s*$` (or just `$` if your input does not contain trailing whitespace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?!.*[-:](\b(?:city|type2?|price):).*\1)filter:((city:([a-z0-9]+))((-type:([a-z0-9]+))|(-type2:([a-z0-9]+))|(-price:([0-9]+)))*)\s*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rH1wG1/6)

The lookahead `(?!.*[-:](\b(?:city|type2?|price):).*\1)` will check (right at the beginning of a string) and fail the match if a string contains (somewhere inside) `-` or `:` followed with whole words (as `\b` is a word boundary) `city`, or `type`, or `type2` , or `price` followed with `:` (this key is captured into Group 1 with the `(...)`) and then some 0+ characters (`.*`) and then the same captured key (as `\1` is a backreference to the captured value).

The `\s*$` will allow trailing whitespace and the end-of-string and will disallow unknown filters.

To shorten the pattern, in PCRE/Boost, you can use

```
^(?!.*[-:](\b(?:city|type2?|price):).*\1)filter:(city|type2?|price):([a-z0-9]+)(?:-(?2):(?3))*\s*$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rH1wG1/5) (in Ruby, `\g<1>` and `\g<2>` can be used instead of `(?1)` and `(?2)`).

If the regex flavor is different and does not allow recursion, use

```
^(?!.*[-:](\b(?:city|type2?|price):).*\1)filter:(?:city|type2?|price):[a-z0-9]+(?:-(?:city|type2?|price):[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/rH1wG1/7)

Comment: This will match unexpected input: filter:city:some-type2:123-type:aaa-price:111-something:anything-...etc..   (unexpected: "-something:anything-...etc..") Is there a way to make aceptable list of names (city|type|type2|price|something) and use same list in non-repeating (first part) of regex ?

Comment: None of the above patterns match `filter:city:some-type2:123-type:aaa-price:111-something:anything-` please check again.

Comment: ^(?!.*[-:](\b(?:filter|city|type|type2|price):).*\1)filter:(?:city|type2?|price):[a-z0-9]+(?:-(?:city|type2?|price):[a-z0-9]+)*$

here is final one, I put filter in first list, to exclude to call "filter" again. This is solved, thanks a lot !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! You are the guru